# Txt to tfrecords conversion

Tags: python, annotations, bounding-box, tfrecord

I'm trying to convert my annotations (YOLO format in .txt files) to tfrecords.
In my dataset (people detection from top view) folder I have about 4000 .jpgs and a .txt file for each photo.
In every .txt file there are multiple annotations for each person in that photo.

I got this code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import cv2
import os
import hashlib

import config
import dataset_util

def parse_test_example(f, images_path):
    height = None # Image height
    width = None # Image width
    filename = None # Filename of the image. Empty if image is not from file
    encoded_image_data = None # Encoded image bytes
    image_format = b'jpeg' # b'jpeg' or b'png'

    filename = f.readline().rstrip()
    if not filename:
        raise IOError()
    filepath = os.path.join(images_path, filename)

    image_raw = cv2.imread(filepath)

    encoded_image_data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
    key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_image_data).hexdigest()

    height, width, channel = image_raw.shape

    is_good_ratio = 1.2 < width/height < 1.25
    if not is_good_ratio:
        return None
    
    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(height)),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(width)),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
        }))


    return tf_example


def parse_example(f, images_path):
    height = None # Image height
    width = None # Image width
    filename = None # Filename of the image. Empty if image is not from file
    encoded_image_data = None # Encoded image bytes
    image_format = b'jpeg' # b'jpeg' or b'png'

    xmins = [] # List of normalized left x coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    xmaxs = [] # List of normalized right x coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    ymins = [] # List of normalized top y coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    ymaxs = [] # List of normalized bottom y coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    classes_text = [] # List of string class name of bounding box (1 per box)
    classes = [] # List of integer class id of bounding box (1 per box)
    poses = []
    truncated = []
    difficult_obj = []

    filename = f.readline().rstrip()
    if not filename:
        print("FN:"+filename)
        raise IOError()

    print(filename)
    
    filepath = os.path.join(images_path, filename)

    image_raw = cv2.imread(filepath)

    encoded_image_data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
    key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_image_data).hexdigest()

    height, width, channel = image_raw.shape

    face_num = f.readline().rstrip()
    print(face_num)
    face_num=int(face_num)
    if not face_num:
        x = f.readline().rstrip()
        #raise Exception()
    
    is_there_a_face_large_enough = False
    min_face_width_px = 15
    min_face_width = min_face_width_px/640

    for i in range(face_num):
        annot = f.readline().rstrip().split()
        if not annot:
            raise Exception()

        # WIDER FACE DATASET CONTAINS SOME ANNOTATIONS WHAT EXCEEDS THE IMAGE BOUNDARY
        if(float(annot[2]) > 25.0):
            if(float(annot[3]) > 30.0):
                w_face = float(annot[2])/width
                if w_face >= min_face_width and int(annot[8]) < 2: 
                    is_there_a_face_large_enough=True
                    xmins.append( max(0.025, (float(annot[0]) / width) ) )
                    ymins.append( max(0.025, (float(annot[1]) / height) ) )
                    xmaxs.append( min(0.975, ((float(annot[0]) + float(annot[2])) / width) ) )
                    ymaxs.append( min(0.975, ((float(annot[1]) + float(annot[3])) / height) ) )
                    classes_text.append(b'face')
                    classes.append(2)
                    poses.append("front".encode('utf8'))
                    truncated.append(int(0))


    is_good_ratio = 1.2 < width/height < 1.85
    if not is_good_ratio or not is_there_a_face_large_enough:
        return None

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(height)),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(width)),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
        'image/object/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(int(0)),
        'image/object/truncated': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(truncated),
        'image/object/view': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(poses),
        }))


    return tf_example

def parse_mafa_example(f, images_path):
    height = None # Image height
    width = None # Image width
    filename = None # Filename of the image. Empty if image is not from file
    encoded_image_data = None # Encoded image bytes

    xmins = [] # List of normalized left x coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    xmaxs = [] # List of normalized right x coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    ymins = [] # List of normalized top y coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    ymaxs = [] # List of normalized bottom y coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    classes_text = [] # List of string class name of bounding box (1 per box)
    classes = [] # List of integer class id of bounding box (1 per box)
    poses = []
    truncated = []

    filename = f.readline().rstrip()
    if not filename:
        print("FN:"+filename)
        raise IOError()

    print(filename)
    
    filepath = os.path.join(images_path, filename)

    image_raw = cv2.imread(filepath)

    encoded_image_data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
    key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_image_data).hexdigest()

    height, width, channel = image_raw.shape

    face_num = f.readline().rstrip()
    print(face_num)
    face_num=int(face_num)
    if not face_num:
        x = f.readline().rstrip()
        #raise Exception()
    
    is_there_a_face_large_enough = False
    min_face_width_px = 15
    min_face_width = min_face_width_px/640

    for i in range(face_num):
        annot = f.readline().rstrip().split()
        if not annot:
            raise Exception()

        # WIDER FACE DATASET CONTAINS SOME ANNOTATIONS WHAT EXCEEDS THE IMAGE BOUNDARY
        if(float(annot[2]) > 25.0):
            if(float(annot[3]) > 30.0):
                w_face = float(annot[2])/width
                if w_face >= min_face_width: 
                    is_there_a_face_large_enough=True
                    xmins.append( max(0.025, (float(annot[0]) / width) ) )
                    ymins.append( max(0.025, (float(annot[1]) / height) ) )
                    xmaxs.append( min(0.975, ((float(annot[0]) + float(annot[2])) / width) ) )
                    ymaxs.append( min(0.975, ((float(annot[1]) + float(annot[3])) / height) ) )
                    if(int(annot[8]) < 0):
                        classes_text.append(b'face')
                        classes.append(2)
                    else:
                        classes_text.append(b'masked')
                        classes.append(1)
                    poses.append("front".encode('utf8'))
                    truncated.append(int(0))


    is_good_ratio = 1.2 < width/height < 1.85
    if not is_good_ratio or not is_there_a_face_large_enough:
        return None

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(height)),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(width)),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
        'image/object/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(int(0)),
        'image/object/truncated': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(truncated),
        'image/object/view': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(poses),
        }))


    return tf_example


def run(images_path, description_file, mafa_images_path, mafa_description_file, output_path, no_bbox=False):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_path)
    
    i = 0

    f1 = open(mafa_description_file)

    print("Processing {}".format(mafa_images_path))
    while True:
        try:
            tf_example = parse_mafa_example(f1, mafa_images_path)

            if tf_example is not None:
                writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
                i += 1

        except IOError:
            print('io')
            break
        except Exception:
            print('e')
            raise

    f1.close()

    f2 = open(description_file)        
    print("Processing {}".format(images_path))
    while True:
        try:
            if no_bbox:
                tf_example = parse_test_example(f2, images_path)
            else:
                tf_example = parse_example(f2, images_path)

            if tf_example is not None:
                writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
                i += 1

        except IOError:
            print('io')
            break
        except Exception:
            print('e')
            raise

    f2.close()

    writer.close()

    print("Correctly created record for {} images\n".format(i))


def main(unused_argv):
    # Training
    if config.TRAIN_WIDER_PATH is not None and config.TRAIN_MAFA_PATH is not None:
        images_path = os.path.join(config.TRAIN_WIDER_PATH, "images")
        description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_PATH, "wider_face_train_bbx_gt.txt")
        mafa_images_path = os.path.join(config.TRAIN_MAFA_PATH, "images")
        mafa_description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_MAFA_PATH, "mafa_train_bbx_gt.txt")
        output_path = os.path.join(config.OUTPUT_PATH, "train.landscape.15pxat640_wider_mafa.tfrecord")
        run(images_path, description_file, mafa_images_path, mafa_description_file, output_path)
    
    # Validation
    if config.VAL_WIDER_PATH is not None:
        images_path = os.path.join(config.VAL_WIDER_PATH, "images")
        description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_PATH, "wider_face_val_bbx_gt.txt")
        mafa_images_path = os.path.join(config.VAL_MAFA_PATH, "images")
        mafa_description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_MAFA_PATH, "mafa_test_bbx_gt.txt")
        output_path = os.path.join(config.OUTPUT_PATH, "val.landscape.15pxat640_wider_mafa.tfrecord")
        run(images_path, description_file, mafa_images_path, mafa_description_file, output_path)
    return
    # Testing. This set does not contain bounding boxes, so the tfrecord will contain images only
    if config.TEST_WIDER_PATH is not None:
        images_path = os.path.join(config.TEST_WIDER_PATH, "images")
        description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_PATH, "wider_face_test_filelist.txt")
        output_path = os.path.join(config.OUTPUT_PATH, "test.landscape.35pxat640.tfrecord")
        run(images_path, description_file, output_path, no_bbox=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

How do I modify that code?
I suppose that I have to read all annotations for each .txt file in my folder, is that right? How can I do that?
Help me please, thanks you

That's what I did so far. I don't know if it's correct or not

```
 #usr/bin/python3
#import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

import numpy
import cv2
import os
import hashlib

import config
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
#import dataset_util

def parse_test_example(f, images_path):
    height = 1280 # Image height
    width = 960 # Image width
    filename = 'cam_1_00000000' # Filename of the image. Empty if image is not from file
    encoded_image_data = None # Encoded image bytes
    image_format = b'jpeg' # b'jpeg' or b'png'

    filename = f.readline().rstrip()
    if not filename:
        raise IOError()
    filepath = os.path.join(images_path, filename)

    image_raw = cv2.imread(filepath)

    encoded_image_data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
    key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_image_data).hexdigest()

    height, width, channel = image_raw.shape

    is_good_ratio = 1.2 < width/height < 1.25
    if not is_good_ratio:
        return None
    
    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(height)),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(width)),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
        }))


    return tf_example


def parse_example(f, images_path):
    height = 1280 # Image height
    width = 960 # Image width
    filename = 'cam_1_00000000' # Filename of the image. Empty if image is not from file
    encoded_image_data = None # Encoded image bytes
    image_format = b'jpeg' # b'jpeg' or b'png'

    x_center_box = [] # List of normalized left x coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    y_center_box = [] # List of normalized right x coordinates in bounding box # (1 per box)
    box_width = [] # List of normalized top y coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    box_height = [] # List of normalized bottom y coordinates in bounding box# (1 per box)
    classes_text = ['Person'] # List of string class name of bounding box (1 per box)
    classes = [1] # List of integer class id of bounding box (1 per box)
    poses = []
    truncated = []
    difficult_obj = []

    filename = f.readline().rstrip()
    if not filename:
        print("FN:"+filename)
        raise IOError()

    print(filename)
    
    filepath = os.path.join(images_path, filename)

    image_raw = cv2.imread(filepath)

    encoded_image_data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
    key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_image_data).hexdigest()

    height, width, channel = image_raw.shape

    face_num = f.readline().rstrip()
    print(face_num)
    face_num=int(face_num)
    if not face_num:
        x = f.readline().rstrip()
        #raise Exception()
    
    is_there_a_face_large_enough = False
    min_face_width_px = 15
    min_face_width = min_face_width_px/640

    for i in range(face_num):
        annot = f.readline().rstrip().split()
        if not annot:
            raise Exception()

        # WIDER FACE DATASET CONTAINS SOME ANNOTATIONS WHAT EXCEEDS THE IMAGE BOUNDARY
        if(float(annot[2]) > 25.0):
            if(float(annot[3]) > 30.0):
                w_face = float(annot[2])/width
                if w_face >= min_face_width and int(annot[8]) < 2: 
                    is_there_a_face_large_enough=True
                    xmins.append( max(0.025, (float(annot[0]) / width) ) )
                    ymins.append( max(0.025, (float(annot[1]) / height) ) )
                    xmaxs.append( min(0.975, ((float(annot[0]) + float(annot[2])) / width) ) )
                    ymaxs.append( min(0.975, ((float(annot[1]) + float(annot[3])) / height) ) )
                    classes_text.append(b'face')
                    classes.append(2)
                    poses.append("front".encode('utf8'))
                    truncated.append(int(0))


    is_good_ratio = 1.2 < width/height < 1.85
    if not is_good_ratio or not is_there_a_face_large_enough:
        return None

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(height)),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(width)),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
        'image/object/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(int(0)),
        'image/object/truncated': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(truncated),
        'image/object/view': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(poses),
        }))


    return tf_example

def parse_mafa_example(f, images_path):
    height = 1280 # Image height
    width = 960 # Image width
    filename = 'cam_1_00000000' # Filename of the image. Empty if image is not from file
    encoded_image_data = None # Encoded image bytes

    x_center_box = [] # List of normalized left x coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    y_center_box = [] # List of normalized right x coordinates in bounding box # (1 per box)
    box_width = [] # List of normalized top y coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
    box_height = [] # List of normalized bottom y coordinates in bounding box# (1 per box)
    classes_text = ['Person'] # List of string class name of bounding box (1 per box)
    classes = [1] # List of integer class id of bounding box (1 per box)
    poses = []
    truncated = []

    filename = f.readline().rstrip()
    if not filename:
        print("FN:"+filename)
        raise IOError()

    print(filename)
    
    filepath = os.path.join(images_path, filename)

    image_raw = cv2.imread(filepath)

    encoded_image_data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
    key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_image_data).hexdigest()

    height, width, channel = image_raw.shape

    face_num = f.readline().rstrip()
    print(face_num)
    face_num=int(face_num)
    if not face_num:
        x = f.readline().rstrip()
        #raise Exception()
    
    is_there_a_face_large_enough = False
    min_face_width_px = 15
    min_face_width = min_face_width_px/640

    for i in range(face_num):
        annot = f.readline().rstrip().split()
        if not annot:
            raise Exception()

        # WIDER FACE DATASET CONTAINS SOME ANNOTATIONS WHAT EXCEEDS THE IMAGE BOUNDARY
        if(float(annot[2]) > 25.0):
            if(float(annot[3]) > 30.0):
                w_face = float(annot[2])/width
                if w_face >= min_face_width: 
                    is_there_a_face_large_enough=True
                    xmins.append( max(0.025, (float(annot[0]) / width) ) )
                    ymins.append( max(0.025, (float(annot[1]) / height) ) )
                    xmaxs.append( min(0.975, ((float(annot[0]) + float(annot[2])) / width) ) )
                    ymaxs.append( min(0.975, ((float(annot[1]) + float(annot[3])) / height) ) )
                    if(int(annot[8]) < 0):
                        classes_text.append(b'face')
                        classes.append(2)
                    else:
                        classes_text.append(b'masked')
                        classes.append(1)
                    poses.append("front".encode('utf8'))
                    truncated.append(int(0))


    is_good_ratio = 1.2 < width/height < 1.85
    if not is_good_ratio or not is_there_a_face_large_enough:
        return None

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(height)),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(int(width)),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename.encode('utf-8')),
        'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
        'image/object/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(int(0)),
        'image/object/truncated': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(truncated),
        'image/object/view': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(poses),
        }))


    return tf_example
def run(images_path, description_file, output_path, no_bbox=False):
    f = open(description_file)
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_path)

    i = 0

    print("Processing {}".format(images_path))
    while True:
        try:
            if no_bbox:
                tf_example = parse_test_example(f, images_path)
            else:
                tf_example = parse_example(f, images_path)

            writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
            i += 1

        except IOError:
            break
        except Exception:
            raise

    writer.close()

    print("Correctly created record for {} images\n".format(i))


def main(unused_argv):
    # Training
    if config.TRAIN_WIDER_PATH is not None and config.TRAIN_MAFA_PATH is not None:
        images_path = os.path.join(config.TRAIN_WIDER_PATH, "train")
        #images_path = config.TRAIN_WIDER_PATH
        description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_PATH, "cam_1_00000000.txt")
        #mafa_images_path = os.path.join(config.TRAIN_MAFA_PATH, "images")
        #mafa_description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_MAFA_PATH, "mafa_train_bbx_gt.txt")
        output_path = os.path.join(config.OUTPUT_PATH, "train/output")
        #output_path = config.OUTPUT_PATH
        #run(images_path, description_file, mafa_images_path, mafa_description_file, output_path)
        run(images_path, description_file, output_path)
    
    # Validation
    if config.VAL_WIDER_PATH is not None:
        images_path = os.path.join(config.VAL_WIDER_PATH, "images")
        description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_PATH, "wider_face_val_bbx_gt.txt")
        mafa_images_path = os.path.join(config.VAL_MAFA_PATH, "images")
        mafa_description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_MAFA_PATH, "mafa_test_bbx_gt.txt")
        output_path = os.path.join(config.OUTPUT_PATH, "val.landscape.15pxat640_wider_mafa.tfrecord")
        run(images_path, description_file, mafa_images_path, mafa_description_file, output_path)
    return
    # Testing. This set does not contain bounding boxes, so the tfrecord will contain images only
    if config.TEST_WIDER_PATH is not None:
        images_path = os.path.join(config.TEST_WIDER_PATH, "images")
        description_file = os.path.join(config.GROUND_TRUTH_PATH, "wider_face_test_filelist.txt")
        output_path = os.path.join(config.OUTPUT_PATH, "test.landscape.35pxat640.tfrecord")
        run(images_path, description_file, output_path, no_bbox=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

and that's my current output

> 2020-07-11 12:13:03.636857: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
> 2020-07-11 12:13:03.644643: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
> Processing C:/envs/TFRecords/train
> 0 0.689844 0.172222 0.070312 0.163889
> Correctly created record for 0 images

where these numbers are only the first row of the .txt file

Comment: what have you tried doing so far ? Please post your effort here

Comment: @mishsx I edited the main post